# Value Cannot be null in Ado.Net connectivity

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i am working on WPF. I made small application in which user can add and delete rows. I used ADO.net connectivity.Insertion is working fine. But if i delete any row, it says that: Value can't be null parameter name: entity. Why is it doing so, can you please guide me. Here is code:

```
try
{
    myEntities dbContext = new myEntities();

    if (grid.IsValidRowHandle(view.FocusedRowHandle))
    {
        Name p = grid.SelectedItem as Name;
        dbContext.Names.Remove(p);

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint where `Name p = grid.SelectedItem as Name;` and see what grid.SelectedItem is?

Comment: I am missing a little info to help.  What are you binding to your list (what type of objects)?  The code I see here would assume that the "Grid" (DataGrid I assume), has as an ItemSource a list of objects of type "Name".  Is that right?

Comment: That is not (pure old) ADO.Net, that's Entity Framework, and you forget to mention you're using DevExpress.

Comment: @JFTxJ yes you are right.

Comment: if i delete any single value, error: The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager. what it means?

Comment: Can you tell us in what method (or event, or whatever) is the code we see in your question from?  Is it from a KeyUp event in the DataGrid?  The click event of a button labeled "Delete selected row"?

Comment: @JFTxJ. oh sorry .. It is click event of button labeled "Delete"

Comment: All I can see for now is (like D Stanley proposed) to put a breakpoint in your code at "dbContext.Names.Remove(p);".  Once the code gets there, move your mouse over the "SelectedItem" property of the previous line of code, and take a look at the tooltip displayed; it will contain the DataType you are working with.  My guess is that it will say it is an EntityFramworkRecord or something like that....  (I am trying to reproduce this, but I need more details on what "myEntities" is...)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the problem is here:

```
Name p = grid.SelectedItem as Name;
dbContext.Names.Remove(p);
```

It appears that either `grid.SelectedItem` is null or that `grid.SelectedItem` is not a `Name`.  Run it in the debugger to see what the type really is.  Are you binding the grid to a collection of names or are you creating an anonymous type from their properties?

Comment: i am  binding the grid to a collection of names

Comment: It is saying:  Name p = grid.SelectedItem as Name; Here at Name - -   Error 2 Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

Comment: You're missing a bracket or something.  Edit your question to match the code you have right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Name p = grid.SelectedItem as Name;
if(p!=null) // check null before remove
{
    dbContext.Names.Remove(p);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

if you get null value as `p`, you need to find the reason for that. debug and check the value you get for `SelectedItem` and also can it cast to a `Name`?

you may need to do as below

```
var name = dbContext.Names.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.SomeProperty == grid.DataKeys[grid.SelectedIndex].Value);
dbContext.Names.Remove(name);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Well, that will remove the exception but won't make any changes to the database...